# Stuck with boolean always returning TRUE

Tags: java, boolean, chars

hello i'm new at the java world and i stuck in my code and it would be really nice a litle hel p

im having a problem with a bolean at this code/

```
public class Variables {
  boolean bit;
  String name;
  public Variables(int b, String name){
    this.name = name;
    bit = test(b);
  }
  public boolean test(int b) {
    System.out.println(b);
    if(b==49) {
        return true;
    }
    if(b==48) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }        
  }
}
```

the problem is whatever the number of b it keeps returning true 
actualy what im trying is to get a number 1 or 0 witch is in a chars and transforme in a boolean t/f

thanks in  advance

MORE CODE

```
public class truthtable2 {
  public ArrayList <Variables[]>bits  = new ArrayList<>();

  public truthtable2 (ArrayList <String> inputs){       
    String [] inputsTab = inputs.toArray(new String[inputs.size()]);
    Variables[] bittab = new Variables[inputsTab.length];
    int total = (int) (Math.pow(2,inputs.size()))-1;
    String tab[]=new String[total+1];
    for(int i =0;i<=total;i++){
      tab[i]=(String.format("%16s", Integer.toBinaryString(i)).replace(' ', '0'));      
    }
    for(int i = 0;i<tab.length;i++){
      char[] chars = tab[i].toCharArray();

      for(int x = 0;x<inputs.size();x++){
        int d = 15-x;
        bittab[x]= new Variables(chars[d], inputsTab[x]);           
      }
      bits.add(bittab);  
    }
    for(Variables[] d: bits){
      for(int f = 0;f<d.length;f++){
        System.out.format("%4s %4s \n",d[f].bit,d[f].name);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT

```
'0' -->A false
'0' -->B false
'0' -->Cin false
'1' -->A true
'0' -->B false
'0' -->Cin false
'0' -->A false
'1' -->B true
'0' -->Cin false
'1' -->A true
'1' -->B true
'0' -->Cin false
'0' -->A false
'0' -->B false
'1' -->Cin true
'1' -->A true
'0' -->B false
'1' -->Cin true
'0' -->A false
'1' -->B true
'1' -->Cin true
'1' -->A true
'1' -->B true
'1' -->Cin true
```

EDIT 2

at this execution

```
for(Variables[] d: bits){
          for(int f = 0;f<d.length;f++){
            System.out.format("%4s %4s \n",d[f].bit,d[f].name);
```

i have this result

```
true    A 
true    B 
true  Cin 
true    A 
true    B 
true  Cin 
true    A 
true    B 
true  Cin 
true    A 
true    B 
true  Cin 
true    A 
true    B 
true  Cin 
true    A 
true    B 
true  Cin 
true    A 
true    B 
true  Cin 
true    A 
true    B 
true  Cin
```

Comment: Passing anything except 49 should result in `false`. Show more code.

Comment: i know because this i have the System.out.println(b); to check out here is the output 
>48
48
48
49
48
48
48
49
48
49
49
48
48
48
49
49
48
49
48
49
49
49
49
49
true    A 
true    B 
true  Cin 
true    A 
true    B 
true  Cin 
true    A 
true    B 
true  Cin 
true    A 
true    B 
true  Cin 
true    A 
true    B 
true  Cin 
true    A 
true    B 
true  Cin 
true    A 
true    B 
true  Cin 
true    A 
true    B 
true  Cin


the number changes but not the boolean result

Comment: this totally should work. perhaps your printing of the result asks the same object? try out print(b); pring(test(b));

Comment: post the code of method test. The code is absolutely fine.

Comment: Post the code where you are testing the value of "bit" and the code for your output  "...49 true A true B true Cin". What is printing the "true". That's probably the culprit. The code you currently have for the method "test" is fine.

Comment: Add a `toString()` to `Variables` and call it right after `bittab[x]= new Variables(chars[d], inputsTab[x]); ` and also print `chars[d]` at that point.

Comment: Am I the only one really struggling to figure out this code?

Comment: @user1841450: Can you provide the input strings also?

Comment: yes but will make no cense once it pass via a filereader before

Comment: thanks a lot guys 
fixed how do i close this thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least two major problems and 1 minor problem.

1. Your code is hardcoding the number of zeroes in your binary string. Then, when you try to parse it, you have all these extra zeroes for no reason.
2. **This is the one that makes all the trues** You keep reusing the same `Variables[]` array `bittab`, so each time it gets overwritten. You need to generate a new one.
3. Your `test` function is overly complicated. I fixed it in the below code.

Here is the fixed code:

```
public class truthtable2 {
  public ArrayList<Variables[]> bits  = new ArrayList<>();

  public truthtable2(ArrayList <String> inputs){       
    String [] inputsTab = inputs.toArray(new String[inputs.size()]);
    int total = (int) (Math.pow(2,inputs.size()))-1;
    String tab[]=new String[total+1];
    for(int i =0;i<=total;i++){
      // changed the below line
      tab[i]=(String.format("%"+inputs.size()+"s", Integer.toBinaryString(i)).replace(' ', '0'));
      System.out.println(tab[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0;i<tab.length;i++){
      char[] chars = tab[i].toCharArray();

      Variables[] bittab = new Variables[inputsTab.length]; // Moved this here
      for(int x = 0;x<inputs.size();x++){
        // Changed this to use variable size
        int d = inputs.size()-x-1;
        bittab[x]= new Variables(chars[d], inputsTab[x]);           
      }
      bits.add(bittab);  
    }
    for(Variables[] d: bits){
      for(int f = 0;f<d.length;f++){
        System.out.format("%4s %4s \n",d[f].bit,d[f].name);
      }
    }
  }

  public class Variables {
    boolean bit;
    String name;
    public Variables(int b, String name){
      this.name = name;
      bit = test(b);
    }
    // Totally rewrote function
    public boolean test(int b) {
      System.out.println(b);
      return b==49;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see, there is nothing wrong with your code. How are you testing the value of `bit`? Can we see the wrapping code that instantiates `Variables` and calls the `test()` method?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

change

```
System.out.format("%4s %4s \n",d[f].bit,d[f].name);
```

to

```
System.out.format("%5s %4s \n",d[f].bit,d[f].name);
```

because you are trying to output a `boolean`. `true` has 4 characters, but `false` has 5 :)

**OLD:**

why not

```
public boolean testChar(char c) {
    return c == '1';
}
```

or

```
public boolean testInt(int c) {
    return c == 49;
}
```

**EDIT**

Add this code inside `Variable` class.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name + " " + bit;
}
```

And then insert the following code after 
`bittab[x]= new Variables(chars[d], inputsTab[x]);`

```
System.out.println("'" + chars[d] + "' --> " + bittab[x].toString());
```

and show us the output.

Comment: chars[d] print result
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
1
0
1
1
0
0
0
1
1
0
1
0
1
1
1
1
1

Comment: but for the tostring Boolean cant be dereferenced

Comment: the problem is whem a call the Arraylist<Variables[]> Bits


and print it come all with TRUE i will EDIT to you see that

Comment: have a look at my edit i dont understand why keep returning TRUE

Comment: @jlordo: I fixed it in my post

Comment: you have `"%4s"`, `true` has 4 chars, `false` has 5. Try `System.out.format("%5s %4s \n",d[f].bit,d[f].name);`